# C# Optimal way to get property from all class members of same type

Tags: c#, properties

I'm trying to shorten the code to most efficient way to access a specific property in all the members of the class.

```
    public class Title
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string root { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string shortT { get; set; }
    }

    public class Results
    {
        public List<Title> pop { get; set; }
        public List<Title> exact { get; set; }
        public List<Title> sub { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

`Results` is coming out of a JSON deserialize. It contains members of the same type, `pop`, `exact` and `sub` (the exact number of members could vary). I would like to filter all the objects in `Results` who's `name` contains "jackie"

So what would be the optimal/efficient way to iterate through the Lists of the members (pop, exact, sub) and look at the property `name` and see if it contains "jackie", without having to directly reference pop, exact or sub.
Reason being that the JSON could return more members tomorrow like `pop` or `exact` etc that I don't know in advanced, so I need to find a way to combine them all into a single searchable list (as they are all of the same type).

Consequently is a way to directly reference the property `name` for all the members in a single statement as in

> foreach (string n in Results*.name)

Answer (score 0):

you can make List of that classes and access with expression

```
List<Title> asdf = new List<Title>;

asdf.where(var => var.name == "jackie").ToList().ForEach(var =>
{
     //do actions with this classes var. 
};
```

Hope I help you ;)

Comment: Great this is the second half of the solution, key is how do I combine the various `Title` members from `Results` into a single `Title` list without accessing them by name?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reference all three properties if you want to access what's in them. If you want to view the contents of all three as one collection you can `Union` them.

```
// given that r is an instance of Results
var combinedTitles = r.exact.Union(r.pop).Union(r.sub);
var matches = combinedTitles .Where(title => title.name == "title you want to match");
```

Comment: I figured that, but the issue is that the JSON could return 100 members like pop or sub or exact that I don't know. So I'm trying to find a way to combine them without accessing the member names directly

Comment: You should use `Concat` not `Union` here.  `Union` implies that it will remove duplicates based on equality (and since there's no equality operation defined it'll do that based on reference equality; which is the same thing as `Concat` but with the additional overhead of inserting things into an underlying hash table).

Comment: @Kyle I don't know whether the specific case calls for `Concat` or `Union` but you're right. It's good to know that there's a choice so that they can decide whether they care about duplicates.

Comment: `concat` would throw an exception if the value is null (which could be returned by the JSON deserializer)

Comment: Yes you're correct, I'm still hoping for an answer to the first part of the question

Comment: What is the first part?